# bootstrap stretch flowing element

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

When using Twitter bootstrap, I have a GUI like this:

```
| [label] [input] [input] [button] [progressbar.............................] |
```

I want the progressbar to wrap to a new row if the viewport gets too small, and once its on a new row I want it to stretch to the full width of the viewport, like this:

```
| [label] [input] [input] [button]            |
| [progressbar..............................] |
```

What sort of CSS magic should I resort to for this?

Comment: Tried `@media` queries? Something like `@media (max-width:800px) { .progressbar {display:block;} }`

Comment: Stackoverflow doesnt allow CSS questions?

Comment: You are getting `-1`'s because you have not showed you even tried anything. And people's fingers itches to click on downvote when that happens :D

Comment: media queries did the trick, completely new to css so I was in the dark here ;)

Comment: Great. Will post as an answer then =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

An example:

```
@media (min-width:400px) and (max-width:600px){ /*any screen which have size between 400px and 600px for e.g. */

    .progressbar {
        clear:both; /*clear floats*/
        display:block; /* block contains 100% of parent */
    }

}
```

Therefore you can control the layout with CSS based on screen sizes, types of media (screen, print, etc), type of screen (retina display, etc).